# Using Arrays in a PDO UPDATE Prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have this array of titles.

```
$first = array('title','first_name','surname','phone','email',
'add1','add2','add3','add4','add5');
```

These are both the column titles in a database, and the names of different form items on a web page. By listing them in `$first` I can use this array to link to the database and the `POST` values created on form submission by using the following code.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO first_page_data (" . implode(',',$first) . ") VALUES (" . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($first), '?')) . ")";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
foreach($first as $key=>$val){
    $stmt->bindValue($key+1, $_POST[$val], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
```

This code will create a valid SQL query using the `$first` array (and will also create the correct amount of questionmarks for the unnamed placeholders). It will then loop through the array binding the `POST` values to the correct questionmark.

This code works with no issues, but im now trying to adapt it for an `UPDATE` query rather than an `INSERT`, which is where im hitting a stumbling block:

The `INSERT` query has a full list of database column titles and then a full list of their values, whereas the `UPDATE` needs them in title:value pairs (as far as I can see anyway!).

Is there a way of updating using 2 separate lists (as per `INSERT`) or do I have to split the `$first` array and the `POST` array up into 'pairs'?

***Solution***

The following is the working SQL statement:

```
$sql = "UPDATE first_page_data SET " . implode(", ", array_map(function($v){ return "$v=?"; }, array_values($combined))) . " WHERE email = ?";
```

Its based heavily on the accepted answer, with a few tweaks to get it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a query that looks something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET title=?, first_name=?, ... WHERE id=?;
```

To build the `SET` expression, you can do something like this:

```
implode(", ", array_map(function($v){ return "$v=?"; }, array_keys($first)));
```

Then you can add your parameters the same way you did in your code.

It is important to remember that there's an extra parameter in the query for the `WHERE` clause, so make sure you add that one too. The order of the parameters is important, so make sure the last one is your `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers in the right direction! After looking through how this might work, I think the function($v) and array_keys need to be the other way round? Also I think I want array_values($first) rather than array_keys($first) so the names are returned rather than the indexes?

Comment: Ive posted to the OP the exact SQL query ive used, which is based heavily on your answer, which is why ive accepted. Thanks for your help, everytime I post a question I learn another function - this time array_map. I really dont know how people remember them all!! :)

Comment: Yeah, I learned `array_map` on another question a couple of weeks ago :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way of updating using 2 separate lists (as per INSERT)

No.

However, in case you are using mysql, an opposite action is possible. So, you can still can use single procedure for both insert and update queries, both using field=value format. An example of such a code can be found in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)